# How to calculate margin percent in MDX

Tags: ssas, margin, mdx

I have dimension which divides the single fact value by members.
Ie. ([Dim].[Member1], value), ([Dim].[Member2], value) ..

Can i calculate dimension members margin with this single value?

Comment: You would like to sum the values from the different dimensions? I don´t really understand, can you explain it a bit more so maybe I can help.

Comment: i have one dimension and one value. i need to calculate basic averages with members of the dimension. i have been experimenting with case-statements but no luck so far..

Answer (score 1):

Using calculated member formula as nested iif as:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[margin]
 AS    
    iif([Dim].[Member1] = [Dim].[Member1].&[X],
    sum([Dim].[Member1].&[X],[Dim].[Member1].&[Y], value) / ([Dim].[Member1].&[X],value),

    iif([Dim].[Member1] = [Dim].[Member1].&[Y],
    sum([Dim].[Member1].&[Y],[Dim].[Member1].&[F], value) / ([Dim].[Member1].&[Y],value),

    iif([Dim].[Member1] = [Dim].[Member1].&[F],
    sum([Dim].[Member1].&[F],[Dim].[Member1].&[Y], value) / ([Dim].[Member1].&[F],value),

    etc...
```

Formula is long, about 150 rows :)